# Message Queue Scheduled Delivery

Tags: php, message-queue

I'm currently working on a php project where users can schedule specific email deliveries. They choose a future date and time and the message should be delivered on that specific date and time.

I'm familiar with rabbitmq, because I used it on other projects. Is there a way to use it for scheduling messages to specific dates? Even if they are far away in the future? I tried the delayed message plugin, but it didn't work out as expected and maybe the range of the delay attribute isn't enough because its unit is milliseconds.

Or should I use a cronjob for this task? Or maybe a different message queue which can be used with php and has this kind of feature?

Thanks

Tobias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you [can do with RabbitMQ + delaying strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45549182/579025) but I'd say it works well with small delays. with a big delay MQ is turning into a store as it has to keep them for long period of time.

For big delays you need a scheduler, like this one https://github.com/formapro/php-quartz

Comment: I already solved the problem by using a scheduler. It works pretty fine and big delays aren't really for message queues I must admit. Thanks for your answer, you are totally right.